# ruby: evaluate a special array as an arbitrarily long ternary if...elsif...else statement (or ternary expression)

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm storing some decision-making data in arrays that look like: `[condition, result, ..., condition, result, default]`, so basically ternary expressions (`c ? r : ... c ? r : d`) and I'm evaluating them as such with this piece of code:

```
class Array
  def ternary &block
    # the block checks if a condition is true
    i = 0
    while true
      if i % 2 == 1 or i == length - 1
        return self[i]
      else
        i += yield(self[i]) ? 1 : 2
      end
    end
  end
end

['false', 0, 'true', 1, 'true', 2, 3].ternary {|i| i == 'true'}
  # => 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].ternary {|i| i > 6}
  # => 5 (defaults to last value because all conditions failed)
```

I'm wondering if there's a faster built-in way of doing this or how I can improve this code.

Note: there are arbitrarily many conditions and `[only_possible_answer]` should also work

## EDIT: The answers so far (tested over 1 000 000 iterations of the same array):

### Setup

```
flat = ['false', 0, 'false', 1, 'false', 2, 'false', 3, 'false', 4, 'true', 5, 6]
nested = [['false', 0], ['false', 1], ['false', 2], ['false', 3], ['false', 4], ['true', 5], [6]]
Option = Struct.new :condition, :result
Default = Struct.new :result
class Default
  def call; self; end
  # otherwise:
  # undefined method ‘call’ for #<struct Default result=whatever>
end
options = [Option.new('false', 0), Option.new('false', 1), Option.new('false', 2), Option.new('false', 3), Option.new('false', 4), Option.new('true', 5)]

class Array
  def ternary_flat_slow
    i = 0
    while true
      if i % 2 == 1 or i == length - 1
        return self[i]
      else
        i += yield(self[i]) ? 1 : 2
      end
    end
  end
  def ternary_flat_fast # by @illusionist
    index = 0
    index += 2 until (index >= self.length - 1) || yield(self[index]) 
    return self[index+1] unless index == self.length - 1 
    self.last
  end
  def ternary_nested
    find {|i| i.length == 1 or yield i[0]} .last
  end
  def ternary_options default # by @ReinHenrichs
    find(default) {|i| yield i} .result
  end
  def case_when_then_else(&block) # by @Amadan
    each_slice(2).find { |x|
      x.size == 1 || (block_given? ? block[x[0]] : x[0])
    }&.last
  end
end

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm(9) do |i|
  i.report('flat slow') { 1000000.times { flat.ternary_flat_slow {|con| con == 'true' }}}
  i.report('flat fast') { 1000000.times { flat.ternary_flat_fast {|con| con == 'true' }}}
  i.report('   nested') { 1000000.times { nested.ternary_nested {|con| con == 'true' }}}
  i.report('  options') { 1000000.times { options.ternary_options(Default.new(6)) {|con| con.condition == 'true' }}}
  i.report('  c_w_t_e') { 1000000.times { flat.case_when_then_else {|con| con == 'true' }}}
end
```

### Results

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
flat slow   4.510000   0.030000   4.540000 (  4.549424) # original
flat fast   3.600000   0.030000   3.630000 (  3.656058) # @illusionist
   nested   6.920000   0.080000   7.000000 (  7.252300) # me (as suggested)
  options   7.030000   0.050000   7.080000 (  7.130508) # @ReinHenrichs
  c_w_t_e  19.320000   0.140000  19.460000 ( 19.593633) # @Amadan
----------------------------------- total: 41.710000sec

                user     system      total        real
flat slow   4.290000   0.030000   4.320000 (  4.339875) # original
flat fast   3.360000   0.020000   3.380000 (  3.401809) # @illusionist
   nested   6.180000   0.040000   6.220000 (  6.258939) # me (as suggested)
  options   6.640000   0.040000   6.680000 (  6.704991) # @ReinHenrichs
  c_w_t_e  18.340000   0.120000  18.460000 ( 18.548176) # @Amadan
```

However "unrubyish" it is, @illusionist's answer is the fastest and speed is a primary concern

Comment: This is a very strange thing to want to do. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I'm solving a problem step by step and each step has to check for a few things that don't easily evaluate to true or false. It's really a variable-length ternary expression (the first example could be `'false'.evaluate ? 0 : 'true'.evaluate ? 1 : 'true'.evaluate ? 2 : 3` but sometimes longer and sometimes shorter). What's so strange about it?

Comment: In 15 years of Ruby, I have never seen anyone do anything remotely like this. It's weird to encode things in the indices of an Array this way instead of just using objects. It's weird to have a "variable-length ternary expression", which is a contradiction in terms. I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you'd get better answers by asking something like "How do I check multiple conditions and return a result for the first condition that matches or a default result?"

Comment: And to answer that question, I would suggest representing each condition/result pair as an object and using [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to return the first object with a matching condition (or a default) from an array of such objects.

Comment: Do you understand the result of this benchmark? If you did then you would know that it is extremely unlikely that the result matters. It's hard to imagine a scenario where this is not premature, unnecessary optimization. Do you have millions of conditions?

Comment: I don't have millions of conditions but I am checking ~700 000 expressions on average (often the same one but the condition checking is different), it's not deadly but you can see that when one way takes 3s and another takes 6 or 18, I'm not going to chose 18, no matter how rubytastic it is. Again, if there is a way to reformat the code and make it faster, please forgive the imperfect question and suggest it.

Comment: One obvious performance optimization that suggests itself is to convert an array of pairs into a pair of arrays, one for the conditions and one for the results. This would eliminate the array index branching and make the logic simpler at the same time.

Comment: With my implementation I get: `flat: 3.37s, nested: 6.20s, options (Struct): 6.92s, separate (2 arrays): 3.96s`, my class method is: `self[1][self[0].index {|i| yield i} || self[0].length]`, can it be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fastest among all answers

## My solution

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class OldArray < Array
  def ternary &block
    # the block checks if a condition is true
    i = 0
    while true
      if i % 2 == 1 or i == length - 1
        return self[i]
      else
        i += yield(self[i]) ? 1 : 2
      end
    end
  end
end

class NewArray < Array
  def ternary
    index = 0

    # Loop until you find item satisfying the condition skipping one item
    index += 2 until (index >= self.length - 1) || yield(self[index]) 

    # return the next value unless its the last/default item
    return self[index+1] unless index == self.length - 1 

    # return default item
    self.last
  end
end

class TestMe < Minitest::Test
  def test_array
    assert_equal 5, NewArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).ternary {|i| i > 6}
    assert_equal 4, NewArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).ternary {|i| i > 2}
    assert_equal 5, NewArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).ternary {|i| puts "is: #{i}";i > 3}
    assert_equal 1, NewArray.new(['false', 0, 'true', 1, 'true', 2, 3]).ternary {|i|i == 'true'}
  end
end

require 'benchmark/ips'
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("My Technique") { NewArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).ternary {|i| i > 6} }
  x.report("Your Technique") { OldArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).ternary {|i| i > 6} }
end
```

### Benchmark

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
        My Technique    98.295k i/100ms
      Your Technique    73.008k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
        My Technique      1.292M (± 1.9%) i/s -      6.487M in   5.023137s
      Your Technique    891.204k (± 1.8%) i/s -      4.526M in   5.080896s
```

> **Note**: I have created new classes from `Array` for testing purposes. You can however open the `Array` class and add the behavior. It will work as fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have flattened pairs of values into an array. This forces you to go to a lot of extra effort to test the array indices to recover the information originally contained in the pairs (which element is first, which element is second). All of this extra work could be avoided by simply not flattening the pairs in the first place, thereby retaining their knowledge of which element is which.

Because of this, I am going to provide a solution to the problem you are trying to solve rather than tell you how to implement the solution you have chosen.

You can represent each condition/result pair as an object and then `find` the first one that matches:

```
# A condition/result pair
Option = Struct.new :condition, :result

# To hold a default value which duck-types with `result`.
Default = Struct.new :result

options = [Option.new('false', 0), Option.new('true', 1), Option.new('true', 2)]

options.find(Default.new(3)) {|opt| opt.condition == 'true'}.result
# => 1
```

If you are allergic to creating new objects, you can use 2-element arrays as pairs:

```
options = [['false', 0], ['true', 1], ['true', 2]]
options.find([nil, 3]) {|condition, result| condition == 'true'}.last
# => 1
```

But Ruby is an object-oriented language. Creating new objects to solve new problems is exactly what the language is designed for.

Comment: "Ruby is an object-oriented language" – Yes! I am always amazed by what hoops people are willing to jump through in order to treat Ruby as an array-of-hashes-of-strings-to-arrays-of-strings-and-integers-oriented language (or something even worse) when it should be obvious to them that they are fighting the language.

Comment: If it is an XY Problem, what's a better way to do this? knowing that the number of checks is variable and they have to be stored somehow. Also, @JörgWMittag, I'm not concerned about hurting the language's feelings as long as it works and, as of now, an array of consecutive values is the fastest way i've found.

Comment: My answer *is* my proposed better way to do this. Have you read it?

Comment: Also, the problem isn't "hurting the language's feelings". Languages don't have feelings and besides, they hate being anthropomorphized. The problem is trying to use an unnecessarily complex method that the language doesn't offer any special support for when a method exists that is easier and better supported by the language. This makes *your job* harder. The programming language doesn't care one way or the other.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs yes, I did read it, sorry I got lost for a second and thought i was responding to JörgWMittag. Again, whatever the language (in all it's mineral glory) thinks about my solution, it's the fastest i've come up with so far. So if you have a _faster_ suggestion, i'll be glad to take a look, I'm not allergic to objects as long as they're fast.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say this is a bit more Rubyish solution than what you have, but Rein is right - the whole concept is not very Rubyish to start with, and you'd probably profit from asking a different, more specific question.

```
module ArrayWithCase
  refine Array do
    def case_when_then_else(&block)
      each_slice(2).find { |x|
        x.size == 1 || (block_given? ? block[x[0]] : x[0])
      }&.last
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using ArrayWithCase
  p ['false', 0, 'true', 1, 'true', 2, 3].case_when_then_else {|i| i == 'true'}
  # => 1
  p [false, 0, true, 1, true, 2, 3].case_when_then_else
  # => 1
  p [1,2,3,4,5].case_when_then_else { |i| i > 6 }
  # => 6
  p ["only_possible_answer"].case_when_then_else(&:itself)
  # => "only_possible_answer"
  p [false, 4].case_when_then_else(&:itself)
  # => nil
end
```